# Vue draggable changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, draggable

I try to build simple tasks board and have one problem. I build my borad:

```
 <draggable
    v-for="(taskBoardCard, index) in filteredTasts"
    :key="index"
    :options="{ group: `${taskBoardCard}` }"
    :class="{ 'roster__field--dark': isDarkModeOn }"
    class="roster__field"
    @change="log"
  >
    <task-card
      v-for="task in taskBoardCard"
      :key="task.id"
      :task-item="task"
      :class="`task--${task.status}`"
      @open-current-modal="openEditingModal"
    />
  </draggable>
```

But i cant see changes in my board:

```
 methods: {
    log (evt) {
      window.console.log(evt)
    }
  }
```

In my filteredTasts i have

```
    tasks: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Task1',
      description: 'description for task 1',
      status: 'todo',
      complexity: 6,
      priority: 'low',
      editing: false
    }
  ]
```

How can i track actions in draggable?
Thank you.

Comment: your code looks good, at least the @change trigger and the method associated with it. Are you getting an error message in the developer console? If so, what?

Comment: i fogot :list property for draggable, it`s resolve my problem.